# Alternative to JQuery .hide

Tags: jquery

I need an alternative to Jquery .hide which 'hides' all the content in a div, everything, including any html5 videos that are playing and anything else you can think of.

If you go to www.squbo.com and wait for a video to play, unmute it, and then click on the Squbo logo, you will hear the video is still playing even though the parent div it is in was ".hidden" by jquery

```
$("#squbologo").load("squbologo.php").click(function(){ $("#homepage").hide(); $("#squbopage").show(); });
```

Comment: Hiding the div does not hide its content?

Comment: Does this mean you want it to be a non-jQuery solution? Pure JS?

Comment: What's the problem with `hide()` ?

Comment: if you go to www.squbo.com and wait for a video to play, unmute it, and then click on the Squbo logo, you will hear the video is still playing even though th parent div it is is was .hidden by jquery

Comment: Then you want to interact with the player, or remove it from the page, then recreate it?

Comment: @Robin: You should have been more specific about your problem from the beginning. But thanks for updating the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#myIDtag').css('display', 'none');
```

or

```
$('#myIDtag').css('opacity', '0.0');
```

to let the element keep occupying the space where it's in.

Last but not least you also have the `visibility` CSS property, which will likely do the same as `opacity`; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility

Pause the video like so:

```
document.getElementById('home-180').childNodes[0].pause();
```

Tested live on your website through the console in Safari's Web Inspector. Returns undefined, but pauses the video.

Comment: If you go to www.squbo.com and wait for a video to play, unmute it, and then click on the Squbo logo, you will hear the video is still playing even though the parent div it is in was ".hidden" by jquery

Answer (score 2):

jQuery `fadeOut` method:

```
.fadeOut();
```

jQuery `css` method:

```
.css("display", "none");
```

Comment: If you go to www.squbo.com and wait for a video to play, unmute it, and then click on the Squbo logo, you will hear the video is still playing even though the parent div it is in was ".hidden" by jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
$("#divID").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: If you go to www.squbo.com and wait for a video to play, unmute it, and then click on the Squbo logo, you will hear the video is still playing even though the parent div it is in was ".hidden" by jquery